# Is it possible to use dynamically assigned computed properties in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Let's say you have array of menu items

```
navigationItems: [
    { title: 'Lookup', icon: 'search', link: '/lookup' },
    { title: 'Parts', icon: 'view_list', link: '/parts' },
    { title: 'Warehouse', icon: 'location_city', link: '/warehouse' },
 ]
```

- and set computed properties

```
computed:{
    partsDisabled(){
        return (this.$store.getters.parts.length == 0)
    },
    warehouseDisabled(){
        return (this.$store.getters.warehouseParts.length == 0)
    },
    notDisabled(){
        return false;
    }
```

- can I add those computed properties as property to navigationItems objects?

```
navigationItems: [
            { title: 'Lookup', icon: 'search', link: '/lookup', checker: 'notDisabled' },
            { title: 'Parts', icon: 'view_list', link: '/parts', checker: 'partsDisabled' },
            { title: 'Warehouse', icon: 'location_city', link: '/warehouse', checker: 'warehouseDisabled' },
          ]
```

- and use `:disabled="item.checker"` in buttons render loop

```
<v-btn
  v-for="item in navigationItems"
  :key="item.title"
  flat
  :to="item.link"
  :disabled="item.checker" >
  <v-icon left>{{item.icon}}</v-icon>{{item.title}}
</v-btn>
```

Is there a better way to disable toolbar buttons at run-time?

Comment: It definitely won't work if you add them as strings. I'm not a Vue guy but something like `checker: this.notDisabled` should work

Comment: @Chris G I understand that and just was hoping that there syntax trick or other approach to solve problem

Comment: @AlexeiP Is there a reason why using `this` is not an option in your navigation items?

Comment: @Ricky Answer below use `this` and whole array as computed property.

Comment: @Ricky Thanks for interesting question. I also try `{ title: 'Parts', icon: 'view_list', link: '/parts', checker: this.$store.getters.parts.length === 0 }` in data array. As expected it also worked but only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but I would define whole array `navigationItems` as computed property. Here is working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZxmdZ?editors=1111

Your code would look like this:

```
computed: {
  navigationItems() {
    return [
      { title: 'Lookup', icon: 'search', link: '/lookup', checker: false },
      { title: 'Parts', icon: 'view_list', link: '/parts', checker: this.$store.getters.parts.length === 0 },
      { title: 'Warehouse', icon: 'location_city', link: '/warehouse', checker: this.$store.getters.warehouseParts.length === 0 },
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: that's really interesting proposal. I definitely have to try. Thank you